# Do orthogonal functions span bigger function space

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

In "normal" geometry, a number of vectors span the same space, whether they are orthogonal or not, as long as they are not parallel. Is this still true for the function space, or does a set of orthogonal function spanning a in any sense bigger function space, as a neither orthogonal nor parallel set of functions?

Comment: In linear algebra the span is the set of all finite linear combinations. In Hilbert spaces (of functions in your case) people take the closure of the linear span and call it span too. In that case they are putting more elements than just the linear span. They are including the limits of convergent sequences of finite linear combinations.

Comment: Similarly, the notion of basis gets adapted. A basis of the Hilbert space (of functions in your case) is not required to linearly span the whole space but only a dense linear subspace, such that when you take closure that is what gives you the whole space.

Comment: Sorry, i dont really understand, what you want to tell me, or how it answers the question

Comment: Your question is badly redacted and it also sounds like your question is caused by something you saw and didn't understand but are not mentioning. I explained above how orthogonal bases are understood in Hilbert spaces of functions and how it differs from orthogonal bases in vector spaces.